# dropdown list from variable using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two dropdownlist.
In my initial loading everything gets fine.Based on the first dropdownlist the second dropdownlist works..
 my condition is like

```
if(batchType==1||batchType==3){

//here i need to regain values after getting nulled by the else part

}else{

$("#dept").html("");//makes the second dropdownlist null

}
```

while the else part excecutes,the second dropdownlist becomes null.But after excecuting else part,if the condition will again like "if" part it again shows null.For that i am storing the values inside a variable department.But how to repopulate it from my "if" section...

`var department=$('#dept').html();`

In my alert i get like

```
<option value="1">CS</option>
<option value="2">Mechanical</option>
<option value="3">Civil</option>
```

Any help will be highly appreciable

Comment: Please share the code online

Comment: if I understood correctly you can either disable 2nd drop down or create drop down dynamically instead of setting HTML to empty

Comment: @rupesh_padhye i cannot hide it because of appearence of screen.

Comment: Share the code of `if` part. How you are regaining that `html` value?

Comment: @JohnR actually that was my question.I need to regain nullified code at "if"

Comment: @Miller In that `if` part, did `department` variable holds that `html` element, which has been stored in it?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you hide the options rather than clearing them, [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/xduk3qtz/)

```
$( "#dept option" ).val("");
$( "#dept option" ).hide();

<select id="dept">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">CS</option>
    <option value="2">Mechanical</option>
    <option value="3">Civil</option>
</select>
```

you can later show the same options by doing

```
$( "#dept option" ).show();
```

Comment: hiding i tried,due to appearance,i cannot change it,it will hides the entire div

Comment: @Miller is there a div inside a select box? Sorry, I didn't get which div are you talking about. You just need to hide teh options, not the divs.